# What is the physical meaning of taking $d\ll \lambda$?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I'm studying electromagnetic radiation from Jackson's book, but I have a question. I understand that electromagnetic radiation is the flux of  electromagnetic energy to infinity, according with Griffiths' definition, but I have a problem;
When Jackson (Third Edition 1999, page 408) consider a localized oscillating source and calculate the vector potential $\boldsymbol A$, he takes the limit $d\ll \lambda$, where $d$ is the characteristic dimension of the source and $λ$ is the characteristic wavelength of the fields. What I don't understand is, what is the physical meaning of this limit?. I know that $d\ll \lambda$ means that the source is small and the light waves are big, like knzhou said, but What I want to know is: why do we have to consider this limit?, why can not we study radiation from a big source, a source bigger than the characteristic wavelength?

Comment: Uh, it means that the characteristic dimension of the source is much less than the characteristic wavelength of the fields. That means the source is small and the light waves are big.

Comment: lumped element circuits; an oscillating circuit is an inductor and a capacitor

Comment: we can indeed study radiation from a big source, and this has been done, but for the purposes of that particular example, the d<< lambda condition allows the math in the analysis to be greatly simplified.